# Array length Definition with mathematical operation in c

Tags: c

I want to define an Array in c in followed way:

```
#define MACRO1 5U
#define MACRO2 6U
int arr[MACRO1+MACRO2];
```

my question is: Is Array arr a dynamical defined Array in Heap or static defined Array in DATA-Segment(or BSS)?

I think, arr is a dynamic defined array. It is similar with an array allocated with malloc function. The reason is, that the mathematical addition will be done firstly in runtime. In Compilertime all macros will be only expanded as followed:

```
int arr[5U+6U];
```

I used a Compiler with c90 Standard.

Can anybody help me? Is my argumentation Right?

Comment: It is static as you defined the array at file scope. The macros are evaluated, and added, at compile time. `malloc` has nothing to do with it. If you had defined the array within a function as a local array, there would still be no call to `malloc`. It would be a plain automatic variable.

Comment: *"I think, arr is a dynamic defined array"* It is not.

Comment: Prove to whom? Look at the disassembly. Or, alternatively learn what "*constant expression*" in C is.

Comment: Or try the google.

Comment: You mean, the Macro Operation will be always done at compiletime? If i define a macro so : #define MACRO 6+7 and i use this macro so a=MACRO-b. And this Equation will be expanded at compiletime: a=15-b?

Comment: Yes yes yes yes yes. No. 6 + 7 = 13. And anyway you must always use brackets - `#define MACRO (6+7)`. Consider what would happen here: `a=MACRO * b`

Comment: Thank you. I understand now. The arr which i defined in filescope is a static varible, because this macro operation will be done at compiletime. Also the expanded Macro "5U+7U" is a constant expression. And constant expression will be always done at compiletime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
#define MACRO1 5U
#define MACRO2 6U
int arr[MACRO1+MACRO2];
```

is equivalent to this:

```
int arr[5U+6U];
```

Since `5U+6U` is a *constant expression*, it's evaluated at compile time, just as if you had written:

```
int arr[11U];
```

or, since the particular type of an array length is not part of the array's type:

```
int arr[11];
```

Since the length is a constant expression, `arr` is not a *variable-length array* (VLA), and it's legal to define it at file scope. (C90 did not have VLAs. C11 made support for them optional.)

If `arr` is defined inside a function without the `static` keyword, it has *automatic storage duration*; in most implementations, this means it's allocated on the "stack". Otherwise, it has *static storage duration* (it exists for the entire execution of the program, and it's allocated in whatever manner the implementation uses (perhaps a BSS segment or something similar). It will not be allocated in the same manner as by a call to `malloc()` (on the "heap").

Constant expressions are defined in section 6.6 of the current C standard (see the [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) draft).

A *constant expression* may not contain assignment, decrement, increment, function-call, or comma operators, unless they're in a subexpression that's not evaluated. An *integer constant expression* may only have operands that are integer constants, enumeration constants, character constants, `sizeof` expressions whose results are integer constants, and a handful of other things.

Comment: Did not follow the [`int arr[11U];` "since the particular type of an array length is not part of the array's type:" `int arr[11];`].  Why imply the size is made into an `int`?

Comment: @chux: I didn't mean to imply that it's an `int`, merely that it doesn't matter whether it's an `int` or an `unsigned int`.

Comment: OK.  As I see it, the number `n` between the `[]`, has some _integer_ type up to `intmax_t/uintmax_t` and would have a value in the range of [1...(SIZE_MAX-1)]`.

Comment: @chux: There's actually no constraint that requires the value to be in the range 1..`SIZE_MAX`-1 -- but anything bigger than that (or approaching it) is likely to exceed the implementation's capacity.

Comment: Hmm, with any array like `char A[some_constant]`, does not `A`'s size must fit in `size_t` as that is the return type of `sizeof(A)` and the definition of `SIZE_MAX` is the max value of type `size_t`.  So, aside for a +1 issue, could an array's size exceed `SIZE_MAX`?

Comment: @chux: That's a complicated question, and the standard is unclear. As I said, there's no relevant constraint on array types, so a compiler isn't required to accept `int arr[LUDICROUSLY_HUGE_NUMBER];`. In practice, any sane implementation will almost certainly make `size_t` wide enough to represent the size of any object it can support. But in theory (IMHO) `sizeof arr` is an integer expression like any other, and I see no explicit reason to assume it can't overflow the bounds of `size_t`. What happens if `sizeof arr` overflows is an interesting question. Does it wrap around, or is it UB?

Comment: Fair enough - thanks for the response - perhaps this will make a good SO question.

Comment: Correction to my previous comment: I meant that a compiler isn't required to *reject* (or diagnose) `int arr[LUDICROUSLY_HUGE_NUMBER];`

Answer (score 0):

when u do

```
#define MACRO1 5U
#define MACRO2 6U
int arr[MACRO1+MACRO2];
```

the c compiler just sees

```
int arr[11];
```

which is probably not 'dynamic' - I quote dynamic because you dont define what 'dynamic'  means for you.

Where it gets allocated depends on where the statement appears in the program. Its either on the stack if its in a function or its static if its at file scope

Comment: The preprocessor is actually part of the compiler (even if it's implemented separately). But the post-preprocessor part of the compiler sees `int arr[5U+6U]`. Since `5U+6U` is a constant expression, it evaluates it.

Answer (score 0):

`arr` is an array whose size is determined at compile time. In C terminology, it's an array that isn't a variable length array. That's because its size is a constant. The variable can be annotated as `static` or put at file scope, and that makes it a global variable, with a size that can be reserved statically (typically included in the BSS, if the C implementation has a BSS).

Any expression that is understood by the preprocessor is a constant. For example, you can have a preprocessor directive

```
#if MACRO1 + MACRO2 > 4
…
```

The preprocessor (which is part of the C compiler) performs the computation (looking up the values of `MACRO1` and `MACRO2`, performing the addition and the comparison) in an early stage of the compilation.

There are also constants that the preprocessor cannot calculate, mostly resulting from `sizeof`: the result of `sizeof` is a compile-time constant unless the calculation involves the size of a variable length array. So while you cannot write `#if sizeof(some_type) > 4`, you can write things like

```
static unsigned char b[sizeof(x) * 2];
static c = sizeof(x) | 4;
```

The size of the array `b` and the value used to initialize `c` are both compile-time constants.

Basically, any expression that doesn't involve the value of a variable or a pointer dereference is a compile-time constant (“constant expression” in the terminology used by the C standard).

On the other hand, the value of a variable (as opposed to a macro) is not a compile-time constant, so it cannot be used where a compile-time constant is required¹.

```
const x = 3; /* OK */
static c = x; /* not ok in C */
```

¹  <sub>C++ works differently here. My answer is about C.</sub>